# Is there any way I can put turn by turn navigation using mapview in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

I have a situation here. I want to put turn by turn navigation using mapview in my android app, just like google maps provides us. I was not able to find any kind of turning info in th kml file returned by google, so I wonder is it possible or not ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution in kml file only. It provides me the Strings for turnings. So I parsed it and it'll do.